# Captcha Size Folder is Massive 50GB

Tags: magento2

We have an issues on a MG2 site, where the Captcha folder is like 50GB. Is it safe to FTP into this folder and remove any old images?

Are there any steps I need to do beforehand. As I do not want to break the site or cause any downtime.

Rob.

Comment: yes, you can move all files from that folder

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's safe to remove old captcha images, you should do that when few customers may access the site such as late night or early morning.

Looks like your cron isn't running or cronjob to remove expired, old captcha images does not run. You have to check cron to avoid the captcha images folder going huge.

You can check if magento crontab is running on your site by running command in your magento root directory: `crontab -l`

Check if captcha cronjob was run or not by run the MySql query:

```
`SELECT * FROM `cron_schedule` WHERE job_code = 'captcha_delete_old_attempts' OR `job_code` = 'captcha_delete_expired_images' ORDER BY created_at DESC`
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the info :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. If the answer works as expected, could you please accept the answer to help others know the issue is resolved?
Btw, I'm available for hire. So if you need to hire someone to customise your site, you can hire me.